# A little warning

Tags: c++

ERROR WARNING:
**instancebase.cpp(607): warning C4715: 'CInstanceBase::GetPrestigeGrade' : not all control paths return a value**

CODE:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_TITLE_SYSTEM
int CInstanceBase::GetPrestige()
{
    return m_sPrestige;
}

UINT CInstanceBase::GetPrestigeGrade()
{
    int pTitle_vegas[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };

    if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[1])
        return 0;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[2])
        return 1;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[3])
        return 2;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[4])
        return 3;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[5])
        return 4;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[6])
        return 5;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[7])
        return 6;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[8])
        return 7;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[9])
        return 8;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[10])
        return 9;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[11])
        return 10;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[12])
        return 11;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[13])
        return 12;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[14])
        return 13;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[15])
        return 14;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[16])
        return 15;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[17])
        return 16;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[18])
        return 17;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[19])
        return 18;
    else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[0])
        return 19;
}
#endif
```

it's a binary source..
how can i rewrite the code to disable this warning ?
im beginner

Comment: By adding `return ***something***;` at the end of the function. The final `else if` might not be satisfied.

Comment: Hint: what is your return value if the last `if` is false as well?

Comment: That's not just a _"little warning"_ but a serious bug, and will cause _undefined behavior_ of your code.

Comment: ... or remove the last `if` and make the last code block unconditional. `else return 19;` but actually all the `else`s only serve to clutter the code, since each is preceded by `return X;` and they can all be removed.

Comment: "how can i rewrite the code to disable this warning?" - Easy; return a value at the end of the function.

Comment: else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[0])
  return 0; that will be ok?

Comment: @DutzųDutzų Not to mention you should handle that in a loop and maybe use a `std::map`.

Comment: Off-topic:  See `std::find`.  If the find is successful, return the *position - 1*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `return` statement at the end of the function for when the last condition is `false`. So the last section can be changed from

```
else if (m_sPrestige == pTitle_vegas[0])
    return 19;
```

to this

```
return 19;
```

Actually all the `else`s only serve to clutter the code, since each is preceded by `return X;` and they can all be removed.

But the function can be radically simplified to

```
UINT CInstanceBase::GetPrestigeGrade()
{
    if(m_sPrestige == 0) {
        return 19;
    }
    return m_sPrestige - 1;
}
```

Comment: so how to do , just return 19; or simplified?

Comment: If you have covered everything else there are no other values it can be.